# Failure to be able to access classes from imported libraries

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, gremlin-server, datastax-enterprise-graph

My research team wrote a script for loading some data from edn files into a Titan database. We are now attempting to migrate our work to a Datastax Enterprise Graph database. When we use `:load` on gremlin-server the script gets through the import statements but fails as soon as it hits any instance of a class from one of the imported libraries. For instance we import

```
import static us.bpsm.edn.parser.Parsers.defaultConfiguration;
import us.bpsm.edn.*;
import us.bpsm.edn.parser.*;
import us.bpsm.edn.printer.*;
```

and after the import we call

```
parser = Parsers.newParser(defaultConfiguration())
```

but gremlin returns "No such property: Parsers for class: Script2"

When running the commands one at a time we run into the same issue. Our initial thoughts are that we need to add the libraries to the right class path, but we have tried a few spots with little avail. When we switch from remote to local gremlin we are able to load the script, but don't have access to the graphs in system.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at dse graph loader

Comment: We have, the file type we use isn't supported. A fair amount of data processing occurs in our script so it would be an involved process writing a script to convert our data files. It would be ideal if we can use our current script with the gremlin server. Thanks @phact

Answer (score 0):

MFin, you're on the right track, essentially you will want to add the libraries to the class path on each of the nodes as well as locally.